# Does Microsoft change the name of NetConnectionID when I run a VBS file?

Tags: vbscript

The following code disable local connection and enable wirless connection, it worked well before.

Recently my windows 7 with 64 has updated, I find the code does't work, why?

BTW, I think that maybe Microsoft change the name of NetConnectionID, but I'm not sure.

**my.vbs**

```
Set WMI=GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
Set w=WMI.ExecQuery("select * from WIN32_NetworkAdapter")
For Each i In w
   If i.NetConnectionID="本地连接" Then     
      i.Disable()    
   End If
  If i.NetConnectionID="无线网络连接" Then     
      i.Enable()    
   End If
next

WScript.Sleep  3000 

CreateObject("WScript.Shell").run "netsh wlan connect name=weiiPhone6",0
```

**Modified Code**

```
Dim retValue

Set WMI=GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
Set w=WMI.ExecQuery("select * from WIN32_NetworkAdapter")
For Each i In w
   If i.NetConnectionID="本地连接" Then     
      retValue = i.Disable()    
   End If
   If i.NetConnectionID="无线网络连接" Then     
      retValue = i.Enable()    
   End If
   If retValue <> 0 Then
      'Check return value for the specific error.
      MSGBOX retValue
   End If
   retValue = 0
Next

WScript.Sleep  3000 

CreateObject("WScript.Shell").run "netsh wlan connect name=weiiPhone6",0
```

Comment: Now, I tested.  i.NetConnectionID="本地连接"  is OK,   it seems that i.Disable() and i.Enable() don't be launched!

Comment: Maybe Windows 7 Operation system block vbs to enable or disble network connection, but I have closed Microsoft Security Essentials and Windows Defener！

Answer (score 1):

It's likely due to not running the script with elevated permissions. If you are confident the `If` statements are being run, try checking the return value from the `Enable()` and `Disable()` methods.

```vb
Dim retValue

Set WMI=GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
Set w=WMI.ExecQuery("select * from WIN32_NetworkAdapter")
For Each i In w
   If i.NetConnectionID="本地连接" Then     
      retValue = i.Disable()    
   End If
   If i.NetConnectionID="无线网络连接" Then     
      retValue = i.Enable()    
   End If
   If retValue <> 0 Then
      'Check return value for the specific error.
      
   End If
   retValue = 0
Next

WScript.Sleep  3000 

CreateObject("WScript.Shell").run "netsh wlan connect name=weiiPhone6",0
```

---

#### Useful Links

- [Win32_NetworkAdapter class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394216(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Thanks! Would you please have a look at my modified code,  retValue display 5, I don't know what means!

Comment: @HelloCW [WMI Error Constants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394559(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @HelloCW Think you will find that System Error Code 5 is Access Denied. So, it appears it is permissions as I suggested in my answer. Just lookup Windows Error Code 5 in Google.

Comment: I have to create a shortcut just like C:\Windows\System32\wscript.exe C:\Users\cuiwei\Desktop\Other\DisConnect_V3.vbs and run it as Administrator by right-clicking mouse to select the item, it's too complex

Comment: I can't understand why it worked well before, but at present it require Administrator role

Comment: @HelloCW because Microsoft introduced a little thing called UAC *(User Account Control)*. Just run an elevated command prompt and load the script using `cscript.exe`. There are lots of questions that deal with running scripts with elevated permissions, good luck.